# How many sequences of the form $1a_1a_2...a_n1$ have each $a_i$ dividing the sum of its two neighbors?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

For each
$n \in \mathbb{N}
$,
how many sequences of the form 
$1a_1a_2...a_n1$ 
with the $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$
 have each $a_i$ dividing the sum of its two neighbors?

I just came across this,
and thought it was neat,
so I thought I would
propose it.

That's the context.

Comment: $1a_1a_2...a_n1$ looks like a decimal expansion to me. I assume you mean $(1,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,1)$.

Comment: Note that it implies $\gcd(a_i,a_{i+1})=1$ for all $i$. Also, any sequence of $1$'s and $2$'s without consecutive $2$'s works. I'm sure there's a nice expression for that number in terms of $n$....

Comment: Also $a_i = i+1$ works. So we have any concatenation $(1, S_1,1,S_2,\ldots,1, S_r,1)$, where each $S_i$ is of the form $(2,1,2,1,\ldots,2)$ or $(2,3,4,\ldots,m$). In fact, $(2,1,2,1,\ldots,2)$ is just a concatenation of sequences of the second form with $m=2$.

Comment: But $(1,2,5,3,1)$ is also valid, so this doesn't capture all such sequences.

Comment: Reversing a valid sequence yields another valid sequence.

Comment: Do you have a solution, marty?

Comment: Hint: Richard Stanley.

Comment: I just spent a pleasant hour browsing Richard Stanley's site, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Look at his presentation on his favorite numbers.

Comment: Ah! So it's the $n$th Catalan number $C_n$.

Comment: Isn't everything?